# prometheus nginx_ingress_controller_ssl_expire_time_seconds still reports ssl of the secret_name that was deleted

Tags: prometheus, nginx-ingress, promql, cert-manager

I'm running nginx-controller (1.5.1) + cert-manager (1.10.1) in the aws eks.

I have changed ingress to use

- cert-manager issuer instead of the sectigo provisioned ssl
- deleted `site.com-sectigo-crt` secret from the `prod` namespace

however my prometheus query using old secret_name is still reporting.

```
➜ kgsec
NAME                    TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-2929m     kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      365d
site.com-crt            kubernetes.io/tls                     2      68m

➜ kg cert                    
NAME                    READY   SECRET                  AGE
site.com-crt            True    site.com-crt   68m
```

#### promql query

```
round((avg(nginx_ingress_controller_ssl_expire_time_seconds) by (host, secret_name) - time()) / (24 * 3600))
```

#### results in:

```
{host="*.site.com", secret_name="site.com-crt"}           90
{host="*.site.com", secret_name="site.com-sectigo-crt"}   1
```

so how to get rid of that line in promql? I expected prometheus to delete that as the secret `site.com-sectigo-crt` has been deleted from the namespace